# How Do I Increase the CPU & RAM in a VSCode DevContainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I typically open up my project that contains a `.devcontainer/` directory with its corresponding `devcontainer.json`.

When VSCode opens up, it asks me whether I want to open up my project in the specified container; to which I say yes.

For some projects, the terminal experience and the JS/TS Language Interpreter are pretty slow.

**Is there some setting that I can configure that can increase the amount of CPUs and RAM that my DevContainer will receive?**

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I also really need this

Comment: Did you try with args `runArgs` in `devcontainer.json` with the [Docker run CLI option](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) ?

Answer (score -1):

> The Remote - Containers extension uses "bind mounts" to source code in your local filesystem by default. While this is the simplest option, on macOS and Windows, you may encounter slower disk performance when running commands like yarn install from inside the container. There are few things you can do to resolve these type of issues.

solutions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance

I suggest you to [Use Clone Repository in Container Volume](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance#_use-clone-repository-in-container-volume) since the way in which you are opening the project in the cointainer is the slower way...